# Cartthrob shipping rates per category group

Tags: cartthrob, shipping

Is it possible to have shipping rates for a product's category group?

In our example, we have gift cards of varying denominations. We'd like to charge $3 shipping for the first gift card, but not charge shipping for subsequent gift cards.

We can't use per-order shipping, because they will need separate per item rates for products such as shirts, event registration, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's currently nothing built into CartThrob that will handle that type of shipping functionality. You would need to create a custom shipping plugin.

Comment: Can I set per channel shipping in a similar manner? I could easily create Gift Cards in their own channel.

Answer (score 2):

Could you reverse-engineer a solution using discounts instead of shipping, which could be applied to a category, or a buy x get x off type scenario? Then your other per item shipping costs could still apply?

Comment: It's possible, but I'm getting the instructions from the client on that one. I'll see if they're open to changing it.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to write my own shipping plugin. Once I polish it up, I'll post it up on github. It does selectable flat rates, item rates, and category rates if you've selected the default flat rate.